# How to deal with floating point coordinate values in image

Tags: image-processing, opencv, matlab

I am plotting some geometry on an image. The problem is the coordinates are coming out as floats, so I am not able to plot them. As a work around I am using floor(); to truncate it to nearest Integer.  This works fine in some cases, except that it shifts my image a little bit.

```
  x=9.7 

  x'=floor(x)= 9  //the plot is now at 9 and not at 9.7 as desired, (this is 'shift')
```

But in cases where my requirement is to draw multiple shapes at **equal distance** I am facing problem as the shift (because of floor();)is not uniform for each shape.
It is just like quantization noise in digital communication.

Is there any way I can get around this problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is actually quite a common one in computer graphics. [Rasterisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rasterisation) is the problem domain you are currently struggling with. You may find [Bresenham's line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) a good introduction to the topic. [Here](http://www.netgraphics.sk/rasterization-a-line) is a nice interactive site with a few different rasterisation algorithms.

Hope that helps!

Comment: +1 Reminds me of the discussion: [GL_LINEAR vs GL_NEAREST](http://manticore.deadmediafm.org/2011/05/opengl-texture-difference-between-gl_linear-and-gl_nearest/), if you are into OpenGL. [This page](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Advanced_OpenGL_Texture_Mapping.shtml) is also great and mentions that GL_NEAREST uses *Manhattan distance*.